# Bootstrap css is not working in production server

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a demo site using ASP.NET. Just wondering why my bootstrap css is not working in my production server. It works fine in my development pc. I have uploaded all the content folder and bootstrap.css.

Below is my bundleconfig.vb

```
Public Module BundleConfig
' For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=303951
Public Sub RegisterBundles(bundles As BundleCollection)
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebFormsJs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js", "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js", 
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"))

    ' Order is very important for these files to work, they have explicit dependencies
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
        "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"))

    ' Use the Development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you’re
    ' ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))

    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("respond", New ScriptResourceDefinition() With {
        .Path = "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
        .DebugPath = "~/Scripts/respond.js"})

End Sub
```

End Module

How do I troubleshoot further?

Regards,
Steve

Comment: do you have errors in the console ? Is your css file accessible under the same URL?

Comment: Yes, I agree with SimonaMi.. You just need to check your bootstrap css and js file network path.. and check content is accessible or not.

Comment: Hi, i don't see any error in my console.

Comment: Show us your BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder.

Comment: I updated my post with the bundleconfig class

Comment: Strange. When I create a new master pages locally, the bootstrap is not working as well. I need to add Bootstrap CDN link to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Tools drop down menu in Visual Studio, select Nuget Package Manager --> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution. Then search for, select and install the latest (v3+) version of Bootstrap. This will automatically set it up properly in your project space.

It looks like someone installed it manually in the project, then never made the required changes to the Bundling class. In DEBUG mode, minified and bundled classes are ignored. However, in RELEASE mode, as when deploying, only the files in the Bundling class are referenced, unless you have some other specified in the head section of your pages.

Comment: Hi, I am using web site project instead of web application project.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Web Site template but Nuget should work on that too. Give it a try (back your project up first)?